# Code review via SVN

Tags: svn, sonarqube

Is there any way by which I can extract the files I changed in SVN after a day's work and execute code review on it using SONAR?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [cut-off plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cutoff+Plugin) might meet your needs. There are some restrictions, for example it works on the filesystem date meaning it's probably only useful if you have a CI server like Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is also a part of the mix. Thank you for the info. Also, will this plugin help in actually reviewing only that part of the code in a, maybe 2000 LOC file, that I have added?

Comment: @RamneekKharbanda Not sure what you mean by "review". The plugin is designed to restrict Sonar analysis to only those files which are detected as changed. Personally I'm not a fan. I think you should be looking at your entire codebase at all times. This plugin appears designed to support teams that inherit someone else's codebase. Situations where you're only interested in analysing the quality of code that has been changed by the new team. I understand the usecase, just don't agree with it.